# PostgreSQL row-level security involving foreign key with other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wonder if the following is possible in PostgreSQL using RLS (or any other mechanism). I want a user to be able to get certain rows of a table if its id matches a column in another table.

For e.g. we have following tables:

"user" table:
columns: id, name

```
| id | name  |
| --- | ---  |
| 1   | one  |
| 2   | two  |
| 3   | three|
| 4   | four |
```

"tenant" table:
columns: id, name

```
| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | t1  |
| 2   | t2  |
```

"user_tenant" table:
columns: user_id, tenant_id

```
| user_id | tenant_id|
| ---     | ---      |
| 1       | t1       |
| 2       | t2       |
| 3       | t1       |
| 4       | t2       |
```

Now I want only users who has same tenant_id.

output:

```
| id | name  |
| --- | ---  |
| 1   | one  |
| 3   | three|
```

To achieve this, I need to create policy something like this:

```
CREATE POLICY tenant_policy ON "user" USING (tenant_id = current_setting('my_user.current_tenant')::uuid);
```

but with above policy it's not working as I am getting all users.

**Note:** user & tenant table have many-to-many relationship.

**P.S.** I know we can do this either by join or some other condition. But I want to achieve the above output using PostgreSQL using RLS(row level security)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If row level security is not working that may be because one of the following applies:

- you didn't enable row level security:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE "user" ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
  ```
- the user owns the table

  You can enable row level security for the owner with

  ```
  ALTER TABLE "user" FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
  ```
- you are a superuser, which is always exempt from RLS
- you are a user defines with `BYPASSRLS`
- the parameter `row_security` is set to `off`

Other than that, you will probably have to join with `user_tenant` in your policy:

```
CREATE POLICY tenant_policy ON "user"
   USING (
      EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM user_tenant AS ut
             WHERE ut.user_id = "user".id
               AND ut.tenant_id = current_setting('my_user.current_tenant')::uuid
            )
      );
```

Comment: I am not sure the above policy will work as there is no tenant_id column exist in table "user". I tried that and it gave error.

Comment: I see. I have added a suggested policy.

Comment: I've tried with the one that you've suggested, but with this also I am getting all user of all tenant except one user tenant:

`CREATE POLICY tenant_policy ON "user"
   USING (
      EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM user_tenant AS ut
             WHERE ut.user_id = id
               AND ut.tenant_id = current_setting('my_user.current_tenant')::uuid
            )
      );`

When I ran the policy, In db it's showing in this way:

`(EXISTS ( SELECT 1
   FROM user_tenant ut
  WHERE ((ut.user_id = ut.id) AND (ut.tenant_id = (current_setting('app_user.current_tenant'::text))::uuid))))`

Comment: My mistake. I have now qualified `id` with the table name.

Comment: ohh.. I am not sure that this is the issue because now when I create the policy what you suggested, it's giving 0 result and whey I try to create it's gives error `row violates row-level security policy for table "users"` Any idea about that?

Comment: That's because you are trying to add a row that violates the policy. Use `FOR SELECT` if you want a policy that only affects queries.

Comment: I recreated my db and and added policies the way you suggested, then it worked. Thanks so much!!